# Are the symmetry operators well defined in the context of Projective Symmetry Group(PSG)?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, gauge-theory, linear-algebra, gauge-invariance

Consider the Schwinger-fermion approach $\mathbf{S}_i=\frac{1}{2}f_i^\dagger\mathbf{\sigma}f_i$ to spin-$\frac{1}{2}$ system on 2D lattices. Just as Prof.Wen said in his [seminal paper on PSG](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v65/i16/e165113), the enlarged Hilbert space and gauge redundancy complicate our symmetry analyses.

Now let's take the translation-symmetry as an example. The unitary translation-symmetry operator $D$ is defined as $D\psi_iD^{-1}=\psi_{i+a}$, where $\psi_i=(f_{i\uparrow},f_{i\downarrow}^\dagger)^T$ and $a$ is the lattice vector. As we know, the transformation $\psi_i\rightarrow \widetilde{\psi_i}=G_i\psi_i(G_i\in SU(2))$ doesn't change the spin operators and the projective opearator $P=\prod_{i}(2\hat{n}_i-\hat{n}_i^2)$(Note here $P\neq \prod _i(1-\hat{n}_{i\uparrow}\hat{n}_{i\downarrow})$). Similarly, in the new basis $\widetilde{\psi_i}$, we can define another translation-symmetry operator $\widetilde{D}$ as: $\widetilde{D}\widetilde\psi_i\widetilde{D}^{-1}=\widetilde\psi_{i+a}$. But $D\widetilde\psi_iD^{-1}=G_i\psi_{i+a}\neq \widetilde\psi_{i+a}$, which means that **$\widetilde{D}\neq D$, the translation operators depend on the 'fermion basis' we choose**.  Does this imply the translation operators unphysical?

But the translation operators should be physical, so are they equivalent in the physical subspace, say for any physical spin-state $\phi=P\phi$, does $\widetilde{D}\phi=D\phi$? If this is true, then how to prove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please link to the [arxiv free paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071)

Answer (score 1):

Luckly, I just found that I can answer this question by myself now, and the answer is 'Yes', the base-dependent symmetry operators become the *same* in the physical subspace, here is the proof (The notations used here are the same as those in [Two puzzles on the Projective Symmetry Group(PSG)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77758/two-puzzles-on-the-projective-symmetry-grouppsg)):

Let $A$ be the symmetry operator(e.g., lattice translation, rotation, and parity symmetries, and time-reversal symmetry). First of all, $A$ should make sense in the physical subspace, in the sense that if $\phi$ is a physical state, then $A\phi$ should also be a physical state, this is true due to the fact $[P,A]=0$. Secondly, after a gauge rotation $\psi_i\rightarrow\widetilde{\psi_i}=R\psi_iR^{-1}=G_i\psi_i$, the symmetry operator $A$ defined in $\psi_i$ basis would changes to $\widetilde{A}=RAR^{-1}$ defined in $\widetilde{\psi_i}$ basis, now use the identity $PR=RP=P$ in [Two puzzles on the Projective Symmetry Group(PSG)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77758/two-puzzles-on-the-projective-symmetry-grouppsg), it's easy to show that $\widetilde{A}P=AP$, and hence for any physical state $\phi$, we have $\widetilde{A}\phi=A\phi$, which means that the symmetry operator $A$ is well defined in the physical subspace.

Note that $R$ is the local $SU(2)$ **gauge rotation** instead of **spin rotation**, and in the above proof we have used $[P,A]=[P,\widetilde{A}]=0$.

**Remark:** The *spin-rotation* symmetry operator is a little special in the sense that it is *basis independent* (This is obvious due to the SU(2) gauge structure of Schwinger-fermion representation).