# By saying a physical state has some 'symmetry', what do we really mean?

Tags: condensed-matter, symmetry, operators, gauge-theory, symmetry-breaking

Here our arguments are restricted to the realm of the Projective Symmetry Group(PSG) proposed by Prof. Wen,

> Quantum Orders and Symmetric Spin Liquids. Xiao-Gang Wen. [*Phys. Rev. B* **65** no. 16, 165113 (2002)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.65.165113). [arXiv:cond-mat/0107071](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0107071).

and the following notations are the same as those in my previous question, [Two puzzles on the Projective Symmetry Group(PSG)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77758/two-puzzles-on-the-projective-symmetry-grouppsg).

When we say the projected physical spin state $P\Psi$ has some 'symmetry', e.g., translation symmetry, there will be **two** understandings:

(1) After a **translation of the mean-field Hamiltonian $H(\psi_i)$**, say $DH(\psi_i)D^{-1}$, the physical spin state is unchanged, say $P\Psi'\propto P\Psi$, where $\Psi'$ is the ground state of the translated Hamiltonian $DH(\psi_i)D^{-1}$.

(2) $D(P\Psi)\propto P\Psi$.

I would like to know: **are the above understandings equivalent to each other?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I just found that I asked a naive question and I can answer it by myself now.

(1) and (2) are equivalent to each other. Because if $\Psi$ is a ground state of $H(\psi_i)$, then $\Psi'=D\Psi$ is the ground state of $DH(\psi_i)D^{-1}$, and $[P,D]=0$, therefore $D(P\Psi)=P\Psi'$.

**Remark:**
More generally, when we talk about any kind of symmetry of the physical state, the identity $[P,A]=0$ is the reason for the equivalence between (1) and (2) statements. Where the unitary(or antiunitary, e.g. time-reversal) operator $A$ represents the corresponding symmetry.