# Does the low-energy gauge structure depend on the choice of $SU(2)$ gauge freedom?

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, gauge-theory, group-theory, gauge-symmetry

The starting point and notations used here are presented in [Two puzzles on the Projective Symmetry Group(PSG)?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/77758/two-puzzles-on-the-projective-symmetry-grouppsg). As we know,  Invariant Gauge Group(IGG) is a *normal subgroup* of Projective Symmetry Group(PSG), but it may not be a *normal subgroup* of $SU(2)$, like $IGG=U(1)$. But this may results in a trouble:

By definition, we can calculate the $IGG$ and $IGG'$ of the $SU(2)$ gauge equivalent mean-field Hamiltonians $H(\psi_i)$ and $H(\widetilde{\psi_i})$, respectively. And it's easy to see that for each site $i$, we have $U_i'=G_iU_iG_i^\dagger$, where $U_i'\in IGG'$ and $U_i\in IGG$, which means that $IGG'=G_i\text{ }IGG \text{ }G_i^\dagger$. Now the trouble is explicit, if $IGG$(like $U(1)$) is not a *normal subgroup* of $SU(2)$, then $IGG'$ may **not** equal to $IGG$, so does this mean that *two $SU(2)$ gauge equivalent mean-field Hamiltonians $H(\psi_i)$ and $H(\widetilde{\psi_i})$ may have different IGGs* ? Or in other words, does the low-energy gauge structure depend on the choice of $SU(2)$  gauge freedom?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Again, I just realized that I asked a very naive question and the answer to it is 'no'. Since although $IGG'\neq IGG$, but $IGG'\cong IGG$, therefore, the low-energy gauge structure **does not** depend on the choice of SU(2) gauge freedom (as we wished).

Furthermore, $PSG'\cong PSG$, where $PSG'$ and $PSG$ are the Projective Symmetry Groups of the two $SU(2)$ gauge equivalent mean-field Hamiltonians.